# Avoid double keystrokes for a given set of keys on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I am looking for a program for Microsoft Windows 7 that can prevent the user from inputting the same key twice in less than X milliseconds. The set of keys for which this limitation applies to should be configurable.

Any price and license is fine.

Comment: Posted on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/53u435/avoid_double_keystrokes_for_a_given_set_of_keys/

Comment: Posted on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Is-there-any-application-for-Microsoft-Windows-that-prevents-double-keystrokes-for-a-given-set-of-keys

Comment: Posted on https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160921095503AABgdgQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following AutoHotKey script (gratis, Microsoft Windows). The variable `keylist` contains all keys the repeat rate of which should be limited. The repeat limit is set to `200`.

```
; Thanks engunneer: autohotkey.com/board/topic/45636-script-to-prevent-double-typing/?p=284048
; Thanks throwaway_ye: https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/54g40q/how_can_i_bind_several_keys_to_the_same_command/d81j0we

; The following part must be located in the auto-execute section, 
; i.e. the top part of the AHK script.

keylist = 1234567890qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm

Loop, parse, keylist
{
  Hotkey, $%A_LoopField%, spamLimitNoParam
}    
Return


; This can be located anywhere in the AHK file
spamLimitNoParam:
spamLimit(200)
Return

spamLimit(limitTime)
{
    StringReplace, key, A_ThisHotkey, $, , All
    send %key%
    sleep limitTime    
}
```

---

FYI:

- [How can I bind several keys to the same command in AutoHotKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39678785/395857)
- [Is the FilterKeys feature in Microsoft Windows 7 supposed to prevent accidental repeated keystrokes?](https://superuser.com/q/1128004/116475)